# Centering Text with Unknown Heights Issues

Tags: vertical-alignment

I realize that questions like this have been asked and answered; I've searched on multiple sites and have not found a solution that I've been able to make work for me. I need to vertically center text for unknown heights; I've tried pseudo elements and different display types, including table and table-cell (which is still in my css).

You can see [my site](http://neoqueenhoneybee.com/blog/) for the current result.

I have a slightly altered code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDG44/14/), but the real code is below. Also, I've noticed that the JFiddle code looks different than the result I'm getting on my site. Same code, but the JFiddle version doesn't text-align center. Maybe some other css or jquery is helping my site's code.

The actual code:

```
<div class="pinbin-image">
 <div class="rollover-item">
 <div id="hover">
 <div class="link-text">
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 </div>
 </div>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'summary-image' );  ?></a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#post-area .pinbin-image {
 display:inline-block;
}
.rollover-item {
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#hover {
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 opacity: 0;
}   
#hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#hover { height: 90%; left: 6.38%; top: 4.8%; width: 87%; } 
#hover:hover { opacity: 0.75; }
.link-text {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: table;
}

.link-text h2 a:link {
 color: #333333;
 font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
 font-size: 23px;
 line-height: 23px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 20% 20px;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
.rollover-item:hover .description {
 top:0;
}
```

Comment: I kinda sorta found a work around, since I'm not even sure if it's possible to do what I want it to do. 1) I limited the titles to 2 lines (some were 3-4, which really messed things up) and 2) since it's a mix of vertical and horizontal images, I had to compromise the positioning a bit. For the horizontal images, the titles look like they are center/middle (yay), but for the taller vertical images, the titles look like they are what they are; top:30% as opposed to top:50%.

Answer (score 0):

table and table-cell works fine for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <span id="child">vertically centered</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    height:100%;
    display: table;
}

#child {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and you may not position your link as absolute

try the following in JSFiddle.

CSS:

```
#post-area .pinbin-image {
   display:inline-block;
}
.rollover-item {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#hover {
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #hover {
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    #hover { padding:50% 0; left: 6.38%; top: 4.8%; width: 87%; display:table;} 
    #hover:hover { opacity: 0.95; }
.link-text {
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    }

.link-text h2 a:link {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20% 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.rollover-item:hover .description {
    top:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pinbin-image">
    <div class="rollover-item">
        <img src="http://neoqueenhoneybee.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1381568_549239698487215_587096537_n-750x561.jpg" alt=""/>
            <div id="hover"> 
                <div class="link-text">
                    <h2><a  href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Pokemon: Snivy</a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'summary-image' );  ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

btw. your code is very hard to read.
Try not to repeat the same selectors.

--

From here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Scroll down to: CSS Table Method

Comment: Hi there! Thanks so much for taking the time to try and assist me. The code I have currently was taken from two different stack overflow sources to try to get my desired effect…so I really don't know how to make it 'better'(as I was just excited to finally get it to do what I wanted, mostly). 

That being said, I think there is something in the CSS or query code that is messing things up because when I apply it to my site, it doesn't work for my horizontal images and messes up the white overlay's position.

http://neoqueenhoneybee.com/blog/